# Floating + scrolling navigation bar broken - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been coding off and on for the last few months as practice at my current job, and had created a floating + scrolling navigation bar ont he right side of my website via bootstrap. However after coming back to my website from a 3 week break I found the navigation bar has suddenly broken (no code had been changed). I've tried looking through the code but I couldn't find any problems as to why it suddenly broke. Anyone have any idea?

[This is an older image of the website (before making things a bit less blockish) that shows how the navigation bar on the right was.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEBDn.png)
The bar also changed colour while scrolling, and was always on the right regardless of how far down the page was (floated).

Edit: 
[This is how the right bar has broken (along the top of the screen, and no longer floats or scrolls)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk52k.png)

Edit 2：
After checking, I found that everything works perfectly fine in Microsoft edge and internet explorer 10, but in Google chrome it is broken (can't check other explorers).

Stylesheet code

```
.rightjump {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 180px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    display: contents;
    right: 0;
}

.rightjumplist {
    display: block;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
}

.rightjumplist:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
}

.activelist.active {
    background-color: forestgreen;
    color: black;
}
```

Main HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="icon" href="images/logo-small.png">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="50">

    <!--#Floating verticle contents bar-->
    <nav>
        <ul class="leftcontents">
            <li class="leftcontentslist" style="background-color: lightgray"><img src=images/logo-large.png width="155px" height="155px"></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="horizon1.html">New Horizon 1</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="horizon2.html">New Horizon 2</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="horizon3.html">New Horizon 3</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="try1.html">We Try 1</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="try2.html">We Try 2</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="can1.html">We Can 1</a></li>
            <li class="leftcontentslist"><a id="a01" href="can2.html">We Can 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--#Floating verticle jump bar (right)-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="myScrollspy">
        <ul id="navbar" class="rightjump nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active activelist rightjumplist"><a id="a01" href="#Top">Top</a></li>
            <li class="active activelist rightjumplist"><a id="a01" href="#Bingo">Bingo</a></li>
            <li class="active activelist rightjumplist"><a id="a01" href="#Wordsearch">Wordsearch</a></li>
            <li class="active activelist rightjumplist"><a id="a01" href="#PDF1">Activity</a></li>
            <li class="active activelist rightjumplist"><a id="a01" href="#PDF2">Activity 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


</html>
```

Sorry if any of this is wrong, first time posting here. Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after taking a quick look, it seems like the display element on your "rightjump" element isn't properly set. Currently this is what it looks like:

```
.rightjump {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
width: 180px;
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
display: contents;
right: 0;
}
```

What you want it to look like, is this:

```
.rightjump {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
width: 180px;
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
display: block;
right: 0;
}
```

Note: what I've done here is changed it from display:contents, to display:block. Hope this helps!

Comment: Gave this a try at your suggestion but sadly it didn't change anything.

I did make an edit a little while ago to my original post. It seems everything works fine in edge/explorer 10, but in chrome it is broken, so it seems the code may be okay, but something has changed in chrome :/